# How do I make code runnig in mounted lifecycle hook after page reload

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, lifecycle

I'm making an VueJS app and I need to dynamically output data, according to parameter I'm getting via URL.

But the fetch code running in `beforeMount` lifecycle hook is not executing after a page reloading.

I found that you need to use vue-router's lifecycle hooks to prevent this problem, or setup a watcher, but couldn't get how to do this properly.

```js
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex'
import upper from '../components/Upper'

export default {
  name: 'Tarif',
  data() {
    return {
      allTarifsSorted: [],
      isSolo: false,
    }
  },
  components: {
    upper: upper,
  },
  computed: mapGetters(['allPostsTarifs']),
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(['fetchPosts']),
    compareIds(a, b) {
      if (a.ID > b.ID) return 1
      if (a.ID == b.ID) return 0
      if (a.ID < b.ID) return -1
    },
    calculatePrice(tarifA, tarifCalc) {
      let dif = tarifA.price * +tarifCalc.pay_period - tarifCalc.price
      if (dif > 0) return dif
      else return 0
    },
    goOption(id) {
      this.$router.push('/tarif/' + this.$route.params.tarifId + '/type/' + id)
    },
  },
  async beforeMount() {
    this.fetchPosts()
    this.allTarifsSorted = this.$store.getters.allPostsTarifs[
      this.$route.params.tarifId - 1
    ].tarifs.sort(this.compareIds)
  },
}
```

Comment: How do you know it's not running? Seem like you should add await before mapping your state to component state – `await this.fetchPosts`.

Comment: Unless you're running SSR, all lifecycle hooks should run on a vue instance. I don't think you can slap async before a lifecycle hook, that'd also defeat the whole purpose of them.

Comment: @Javas the thing is I have an asynchronous fetch inside fetchposts function, I'm not sure if hook is not running code, but references to result of this code execution is using in layout in html, and it's showing an error of referencing to undefied data and this problem is not showing without page reload, that's the thing.

Comment: That's it. So you have you store polluted with posts before navigating to that page. Seems like another component already called `fetchPosts`, but when you refresh the page, the store is not polluted. So try to add `await`.

Comment: @Javas add directly to this.fetchposts()? Like await this.fetchposts()?

Comment: @Yakovonthego, `await this.fetchPosts()`.

Comment: @Javas it worked out, content is loading but there's still some problems with 'cannot read property of undefined', despite everything is working. I guess the error occures before content reactively loads to the page.